# Ansible multiple when condition failing

Tags: ansible

in my playbook the first task will find some files and if found register them in a variable and the second task will remove the files via a command passed via the shell, the issue is the second task always errors even when the variable `cleanup` is set to false. This is the playbook:

```
tasks:
    - name: Find tables
      find:
        paths: "{{ file path }}"
        age: "1d"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: directory
      when: cleanup
      register: cleanup_files

    - name: cleanup tables
      shell: /bin/cleanup {{ item.path | basename }}
      with_items: "{{ cleanup_files.files }} "
      when: "cleanup or item is defined"
```

when cleanup is set to false the first task is skipped but the second errors saying: `"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}`.

item would be defined as the task above didnt run so should it still not skip the task as `cleanup` is set to false?

ive noticed if i change the `or` to `and` in the second task it skips the task fine. im not sure why.

Comment: [Also be aware that when combining Conditionals with a loop, the `when:` statement is processed separately for each item.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops)

Comment: @techraf thanks for replying, im a bit confused to where i would use the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the playbook to this code (changes in the second task), and after the code you can see the logic behind the changes:

```
tasks:
    - name: Find tables
      find:
        paths: "/tmp"
        age: "1000d"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: directory
      when: cleanup
      register: cleanup_files

    - debug: var=cleanup_files

    - name: cleanup tables
      debug: msg="file= {{ item.path | basename }}"
      when: "cleanup_files.files is defined"
      with_items: "{{ cleanup_files.files }} "
```

When you execute with `cleanup=false`, the `find` task will register its results to the `cleanup_files`, but you will notice it doesn't have a `cleanup_files.files` attribute. When you execute with `cleanup=true`, you will get the `cleanup_files.files`, it will be empty if no files found to meet the `find` criteria.

So, second task needs to know only if `cleanup_files.files` is defined, and if defined, it can proceed to run. If no files were found to meet the criteria, the `with_items` clause will handle it properly (no files=> no iterations).

I have added a `debug` task to check the `cleanup_files`, you can run and see its structure, when:

1. cleanup=true
2. cleanup=false

Comment: I am curious why your solution would work but mine would not.  :/

Comment: it looks right to me. OP commented on your answer claiming "its not working", but you didn't answer anything back.. :/

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the second WHEN to

```
when: "cleanup and cleanup_files.files is defined"
```

You might also consider making `cleanup` a tag.